# How to add column in Power BI by run R script in query editor

Tags: r, powerbi

1 - Enter a table call : **"Table1"**

```
Year   Profit
2019   300
2018   200
2017   100
```

2 - Run this script in button **"Run R Script"** in Power Query Editor

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script

dataset <- as.data.frame(Table1)
dataset["new"] <- NA
```

3 - Error :

```
DataSource.Error: ADO.NET: R script error.
 as.data.frame(Table1) Error:  no object 'Table1'
```

What is the method to solve this error ?

Comment: I think its because in the R script, `Table1` is "stored" under the variable `dataset`, so you might want to try `dataset <- as.data.frame(dataset)`

Comment: thankyou julien . It returns : i  This table is empty .I just need some simple step to begin shaping data , any more straightforward solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input data from csv : Table1

```
Year   Profit
2019   300
2018   200
2017   100
```

Then, **Open Query Editor** by selecting **Edit Queries** from the Home tab in Power BI Desktop.

In the **Transform** tab, select Run R Script

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script

output <- dataset
output$new <- NA
```

You need to name `output` the output of your R script, here your table with the new column `new`.